# How to automatically set permission at automount without mask

Tags: permissions, filesystems, mount, fstab

I store my data on a NTFS parition to share it with my Windows. I use the dmask,fmask option in my fstab entry to avoid rwx default permissions to everyone, for coherence, security, and also because my zsh color profile rendering is then ugly when listing.

```
/dev/sda5       /mnt/Data       auto    defaults,force,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137   0   0
```

The problem with f/dmask is that I can't change related permissions of files once it's mounted. For example, I have Unix scripts stored there; and when I try a `chmod +x`, the mask automatically discards any changes, even in root.

I thought about removing masks and automatically executing this kind of script :

```
chown -R me /mnt/Data
find -type f /mnt/Data -exec chmod -R 640 {} \;
```

but it isn't very elegant and can be very long for large amount of little imbricated files/directory. Is there any way or unknown (at least to me) option of `mount` to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uid gid dmask fmask` is `mount`'s way of letting you specify `owner`, `group` and `access permissions`. Either you use it and accept the limitations, or you don't. There are a few options:

1. Skip `dmask fmask` and adjust your `zsh` color profile. This seems like the easiest option.
2. Keep your mount options and write a `sudo`-like script to temporarily `remount` the drive without `dmask fmask`, do the `chmod` and `remount` back with `dmask fmask`.

Imagine invoking it like:

```
remount-do /mnt/Data "chmod 755 /my/file"
```

Comment: Well, thanks. I guess I'll just change my color profile then, cause remounting the drive each time I want to set a +x is quite heavy